# python oath2 example with fastapi

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I found an example from this web site,
https://blog.hanchon.live/guides/google-login-with-fastapi/

is there a similar example for microsoft AD authentication?

```
import os
import starlette
from starlette.config import Config
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth

# OAuth settings
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID') or None
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET') or None
if GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET is None or GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID is None:
    raise BaseException('Missing env variables')

# setup OAuth
config_data = {'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID': GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
               'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET': GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
starlette_config = Config(environ=config_data)
oauth = OAuth(starlette_config)
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metada_url='https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'}
)
```

The output is:]On instance['id']:
'10'
Given JSON data is InValid
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample3.py", line 38, in 
invalidjsonData = json.loads(
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/**init**.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode]

user_schema is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "User",
  "description": "A user request json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "description": "The unique identifier for a user",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "description": "Name of the user",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "contact_number": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "required": ["id", "name", "contact_number"]
}
```

Comment: Everyone’s Google skills are as good as your Google skills.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Perhaps you seek client access credentials to a resource via oauth on Microsoft Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

an example from github:

```
import json
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.config import Config
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse, RedirectResponse
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth, OAuthError

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="!secret")

config = Config('.env')
oauth = OAuth(config)

CONF_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metadata_url=CONF_URL,
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid email profile'
    }
)


@app.get('/')
async def homepage(request: Request):
    user = request.session.get('user')
    if user:
        data = json.dumps(user)
        html = (
            f'<pre>{data}</pre>'
            '<a href="/logout">logout</a>'
        )
        return HTMLResponse(html)
    return HTMLResponse('<a href="/login">login</a>')


@app.get('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth')
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)


@app.get('/auth')
async def auth(request: Request):
    try:
        token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    except OAuthError as error:
        return HTMLResponse(f'<h1>{error.error}</h1>')
    user = token.get('userinfo')
    if user:
        request.session['user'] = dict(user)
    return RedirectResponse(url='/')


@app.get('/logout')
async def logout(request: Request):
    request.session.pop('user', None)
    return RedirectResponse(url='/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

Comment: dont forget the env file.    APP_SECRET_KEY='secret key'
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='261....com'
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET='G...4'